# Bug fix. How do I run callbacks and save but not validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some code that looks like this:

```
def checkout(batch, checkout_user)
     ...
    if self.checkouts.build(removed_at: Time.now, checkout_location: batch.checkout_location, user: checkout_user, checkout_batch: batch)
      update_attribute(:library_status, 'Checked out')

      ...
```

I no longer want to have that `update_attribute(:library_status)` line there because I don't want to mark the status as "checked out". However, I do want the checkouts that were built (the association) to save because a bug occurs if the `batch` object is not associated with the `checkout` object.

In the `CheckoutBatch` model:

```
has_many :catalog_items, through: :checkouts
```

The above line is the culprit. Code that looks like `batch.catalog_items` won't return anything unless the `checkout` is saved because I'm getting `catalog_items` through checkouts.

So how do I save the checkouts and kickoff callbacks (like update_attributes does) but not update any attributes? Can I just call `self.checkouts.save`? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just call `self.checkouts.save`. That will run validations, save the checkouts if validations pass, and then run the associated callbacks. If you want to skip validations, use the bang method of save: `save!`.